Audio data received using BLE notifications in iOS swift breaks
I have a device with a mic that I connect to via BLE notifications. The output config of that device is 4000Hz, 32bit integer, stereo (2 channels). When I play the data a lot of noise is introduced. Also, the audio breaks a lot. Is there any way to rectify this problem? Or is getting into the MFI program required here?
Running the same methods in Android GATT works flawlessly.
This is my code for playing the audio.
func processMicData(_ data: Data) {
        let int32Count = data.count / MemoryLayout<Int32>.size
        let int32Array = data.withUnsafeBytes { bufferPointer -> [Int32] in
            let buffer = bufferPointer.bindMemory(to: Int32.self)
            return Array(buffer.prefix(int32Count))
        }
        
        let float32Array: [Float32] = int32Array.map { Float32($0) / Float32(Int32.max) }
        
        let frameCount = AVAudioFrameCount(float32Array.count / 2)
        
        let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: frameCount)!
        buffer.frameLength = frameCount
        
        let leftChannel = buffer.floatChannelData![0]
        let rightChannel = buffer.floatChannelData![1]
        
        for i in 0..<Int(frameCount) {
            leftChannel[i] = float32Array[i * 2]
            rightChannel[i] = float32Array[i * 2 + 1]
        }
        audioPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer(buffer, at: nil)
    }

Also, is it something to do with how fast the BLE API reads the data?

Mfi probably won't help as mfi does not cover BLE devices. Noise in audio data can be caused by big-endian/little-endian issues. See also https://punchthrough.com/maximizing-ble-throughput-on-ios-and-android/

Definitely not a big-endian/little-endian issue. I used web sockets to record the audio packets in android and send it to ios, played in iOS works as expected.
